# Goodness-of-fit value when comparing a distribution to another

Tags: probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared

(Not a mathematician writing here)

Hi there
I would like to find out if the workload distribution within a team conforms to an equal distribution. To that end, I would like to derive a value in the range $[0,1]$ to indicate how well the distribution conforms to the equal distribution.
I know that the $\chi^2$ test can be used to test if a distribution conforms to a "target" distribution, but can I translate this to a meaningful number in the range $[0,1]$?

Thanks for your toughts about this!

Best
Daniel